# How can I know if a user received a refund for non-renewing subscriptions

Tags: ios, app-store, subscription, non-renewing-subscription

In [Technical Note TN2413, under How do I use the cancellation_date field?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2413/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016228-CH1-RECEIPT-HOW_DO_I_USE_THE_CANCELLATION_DATE_FIELD_), there is a small note:

> **Important**: `cancellation_date` is not currently added for consumable and non-renewing subscription products.

However, non-renewing subscriptions do have the option of being cancelled by Apple and the user receiving a refund. I'd like to block off access to my content if the user has cancelled their subscription. How can I do that?

Comment: Simple answer, you can't.

Comment: That's what I thought, but maybe someone has some insight into both why and how, if possible, one could work around that.